# Where did region europe-west1 go?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I'm unable to create a bucket in region europe-west1. Anyone have the same problem? This is what I see on the dashboard:

[image]

When the docs region list looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Tried with gsutil and it works: 'gsutil mb -c regional -l europe-west1 gs://uniquebucketname

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is an issue with the UI. There is an open [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/129670715) that you can follow to get updates on the topic. You can mark it and comment to get notifications and indicate that you are affected by this issue.

At the moment as Carl Engene mentioned in his comment and as it is also mentioned in the [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/129670715) that I have shared above, there is a workaround and you can create the bucket using gsutil command as follows:

`$ gsutil mb -l europe-west1 gs://[BUCKET_NAME]/`